# ffmpeg and the maze of formats and codecs

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I'm running ffmpeg on android.

What I want to do is take a video recorded on an android phone, overdub it with a wav pcm file and save it in a format suitable for youtube upload.
the 3gp is:
Metadata:
major_brand : 3gp4
minor_version : 768
compatible_brands: 3gp4mp413gp6
copyright :
copyright-eng :
Duration: 00:00:12.18, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2002 kb/s
Stream #0.0(eng): Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 800x480 [PAR 1:1 DAR 5:3], 1987 kb/s, 9.77 fps, 60 tbr, 1k tbn, 60 tbc
Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: amrnb, 8000 Hz, 1 channels, flt, 12 kb/s

The wav is plain simple wav file (although I might want to use mp3 also)

The output should be "MPEG4 (Divx, Xvid) format at 640x480 resolution with MP3 audio" as youtube recommends.

someone told me it is not legal to do. why?
What are the alternatives?

Thanks
eli

Comment: Why shouldn't this be legal? IANAL, but I see no reasons you shouldn't write this app. It's not malicious so it should be ok.

Comment: It might be illegal due to patents on the mp3 and mpeg4 codecs.